# Windows 10 host wrongly uses UNIX socket instead of npipe

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker-compose [should use npipe protocol on Windows by default](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/release-notes/docker-compose/#190-2016-11-16), but it doesn't. The following logs proves that (Win 10 pro 64 bit host):

> Log 1: Failed to retrieve
> information of the docker client and server host: Cannot connect to
> the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon
> running?
>
> Log 2: Provider connection error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
> unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

As you can see by the logs, there was an attempt to use: `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. This is a UNIX socket and not a pipe (named pipe), which Windows knows perfectly to handle.

Ok, so docker-compose has a problem with the default configuration. Let's set the pipe explicitly, to take place instead of the UNIX socket ([using npipe of the long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#long-syntax)):

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '3.2'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: npipe                # here we are
        source: ./pipe
        target: /pipe/docker_engine
```

But guess what? We get the same UNIX socket error.

I have also tried: `- ./pipe/docker_engine://./pipe/docker_engine`, but failed once again.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I tried  `npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine` and it worked in my case. (probably the number of slashes matters?).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586535/cisco-ioxclient-docker-package-command-error-an-address-incompatible-with-the-r

Comment: @LeonardAB Thanks a lot for your comment, I'll try that.