# cisco ioxclient docker package command error: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used

Tags: docker, cisco

I was trying to create a Cisco IoX package from a docker image following the tutorial [here](https://learninglabs.cisco.com/modules/iox-basic/iot-iox-app-docker/step/8).

when I ran the command `ioxclient docker package -a leonardab/iox-test:latest .` , I got the following error:

```
Could not retrieve requested Docker image.
Error occurred :  dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.
```

OS: Windows 10 Pro, Docker: 18.09.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the protocol used by IoX to access the docker daemon.
The default protocol is unix, so in the default setting, IoX access `unix /var/run/docker.sock`

To change it into windows protocol, [change the setting](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/iox/#!docker-commands/docker-commands) by running the following command:

```
ioxclient docker init
```

then when prompted, fill in the **windows URL** as explained [in this article](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#how-do-i-connect-to-the-remote-docker-engine-api)

```
Enter the URI for the Docker daemon to use[unix:///var/run/docker.sock]: npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
```

For the API, put the version of the docker API running on your machine (to find this out, open another shell and run `docker version`, you 'll see the API version. see [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/#view-the-api-reference))

```
Enter the API version that the target daemon is running[v1.22]: 1.39
```

(replace 1.39 with your own API version. )

The `ioxclient package` command should work now.